# Build a hash by taking input from file, append the values if key is not unique

Tags: regex, perl, hashmap, nlp, associative-array

I have this file

```
affaire,chose,question
chose,emploi,fonction,service,travail,tâche
cause,chose,matière
chose,point,question,tête
chose,objet,élément
chose,machin,truc
```

I would like to have an associative array like this :

```
affaire => chose, question
cause => chose, matière
chose => emploi, fonction, service, travail, tache, point, question, tete, objet élément, machin, truc
```

or even better, whenever I found a new word, save the word as a key and the context (left or/and right) as a value... So for example:

```
affaire => chose, question
cause => chose, matière
chose => affaire, question, cause, matière, emploi, fonction, service, travail, tache, point, question, tete, objet élément, machin, truc
```

At present time I'm trying to create the associative array in this way:

```
 $in = "test.txt";
 $out = "res_test.txt";

open(IN, "<", $in); 
open(OUT, ">", $out);

%list = '';
while(defined($l = <IN>)){
    if ($l =~ /((\w+),(.*))/){
        #2,3
        $list{$2} = $3;
    }
}


    while(my($k,$v) = each(%list)){
            print OUT $k." => ".$v."\n";
    }
```

But the result is:

```
affaire => chose,question
 => 
chose => machin,truc
cause => chose,matière
```

Why doesn't it add new values?
Thank you for help.

Comment: You don't append, you replace (`$list{$2} = $3;`)

Comment: I believe you need an *array* instead of a string of comma-separated words as the hash values. And when you say, *"save the word as a key and the context (left or/and right) as a value"*, doesn't that mean there should be an entry for *all* the words, like `machin => chose,truc` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You overwrite old hash values when you actually want to append them, so
solution would be to concatenate strings,

```
my %list;
while (my $l = <IN>) {
    if ($l =~ /((\w+),(.*))/) {

      # $list{$2} //= ""; # initialize to empty string
      # # add comma in front depending on $list{$2} content
      # $list{$2} .= length($list{$2}) ? ",$3" : $3;
      if (defined $list{$2}) { $list{$2} .= ",$3" }
      else                   { $list{$2}  = $3 }
    }
}
```

or to use more common hash of arrays for storing values,

```
my %list;
while (my $l = <IN>) {
    my ($k, @vals) = split /,/, $l;
    push @{ $list{$k} }, @vals;
}
use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%list;
```

Comment: why are you using the "length"?

Comment: @Jurafsky length is there in the case `$list{$2}` is zero `0`. `?` is [ternary operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator). For `B ? X : Y` it will take `X` when `B is true`, `Y` otherwise.

Comment: how can I print the result without data dumper? I'm not very good at reference/dereference of arrays and hashes

Comment: @Jurafsky `for my $k (sort keys %list) { print "$k => ", join(",", @{$list{$k}}), "\n" }`

Comment: :) and I thought the way it was at first was a loser on both fronts

Answer (score 4):

Each time you have new value, you assigned this new value to hash key's value, causes the old value is overridden.

A simple fix:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $in  = "in";                                                                                    
my $out = "out";                                                                                    

open IN, "<", $in                                                                                   
    or die "$!";                                                                                    
open OUT, ">", $out                                                                                 
    or die "$!";                                                                                    

my %list = ();                                                                                      

while (defined(my $l = <IN>)) {                                                                     
    if ($l =~ /(\w+),(.*)/) {                                                                       
        $list{$1} .= exists($list{$1}) ? ",$2" : $2;                                                
    }                                                                                               
}                                                                                                   

while(my($k,$v) = each(%list)){                                                                     
    print OUT $k." => ".$v."\n";                                                                    
}
```

Comment: what does it mean here the "?"

Comment: @mpapec: No, there is no warnings in this case, because of `autovivication`.

Comment: @Gnouc yes, there is no warning.

Answer (score 0):

In hash (associate array) the keys must be unique. That is why in your case `chose` will cause issues.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# your code goes here
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my %hash;
while(chomp(my $line = <DATA>)){
        my (@values) = split /,/,$line;
        my $key = shift @values;
        if(exists $hash{$key}){
        my $ref_value = $hash{"$key"};
        push @values, @$ref_value;
        $hash{"$key"} = [@values];
        }   
        else{
        $hash{"$key"} = [@values];
        }
}
print Dumper %hash;

__DATA__
affaire,chose,question
chose,emploi,fonction,service,travail,tâche
cause,chose,matière
chose,point,question,tête
chose,objet,élément
chose,machin,truc
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/iujkZw)

Comment: Your output is : $VAR1 = {
          'affaire' => [
                         'chose',
                         'question'
                       ],
          'cause' => [
                       'chose',
                       'matière'
                     ],
          'chose' => [
                       'objet',
                       'élément'
                     ]
        };
and how can I just add the other values of "chose" key?

Answer (score 0):

```
use Data::Dumper;

 $in = "test.txt";
 $out = "res_test.txt";

open(IN, "<", $in); 
open(OUT, ">", $out);

%list = '';
while(defined($l = <IN>)){
chomp($l);
$list{$k} = [] unless exists $list{$k};
    if ($l =~ /((\w+),(.*))/){
        #2,3
        push @{ $list{$2} }, $3;
        }
    }
foreach $k (sort keys %list) {
my @val = @{$list{$k}};
print join ', ', sort @val;
print ".\n";
}
```

It works!